# Debugging on Motorola MC2180 and LAN connection

Tags: c#, lan

I want to debug barcode reader (scanner) Motorola MC2180 with access to WiFi. For debugging I am using VS2008 and OS of the mobile scanner is WinCE 6. When the scanner is cradled, then all network connections go through the USB cable. So I cannot use wireless connection.

Is there any solution of debugging the scanner with access to WiFi?

Comment: What have you already tried , please include code sample.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has some useful links about `Windows Mobile developers can use the powerful Visual Studio debugging features to examine their code in action.`

You can have a look and get started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158521.aspx

Also, a WiFi debugging blog, which is old, but might be of your help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsmobile/archive/2005/05/22/420884.aspx.